# How do I use Quartz with python installed through homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, quartz-graphics

I can import Quartz no problem at my default apple installed /usr/bin/python, but not at the homebrew installed python at /usr/local/bin/python because presumably Quartz is avalible as a package at the apple python and not the brew python. How can I link Quartz to my brewed python installation?

Comment: which python is your default?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham brewed python is, and I'm trying to use Quartz on brewed python.

Comment: You need to install `PyObjC` for your brew Python.

Comment: @NedDeily pip install pyobjc failed after a dozen warnings, is there something else I'm not aware of? I am going to try installing it manually right now.

Comment: what were the warnings?

Comment: too many to copy. they were the same ones listed here: http://code.activestate.com/lists/pythonmac-sig/23502/. At the end of the email they figured out that an out of date command line tools was the problem. I tried downloading the command line tools dmg from apple   and installing it but it still gives me the same warnings.

Comment: might be something useful here https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html

Comment: For future reference, seems like there is a bug with the new setuptools. You can clone the newest repo at bitbucket to install. More info: https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issue/86/installation-problems-with-setuptools-36